# Finite union of compact sets is compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n \subseteq X$ compact subsets. Then I want to show that $Y:=\bigcup_i Y_i$ is compact only using the definition of a compact set.

My attempt: Let $(y_n)$ be a sequence in $Y$. If $\exists 1 \leq i \leq n\; \exists N \in \mathbb N \; \forall j \geq N\; y_j \in Y_i$ then $(y_n)$ has a convergent subsequence because $Y_i$ is compact. Otherwise,
$$
\forall 1 \leq i \leq n \; \forall N \in \mathbb N\; \exists j \geq N\; y_j \notin Y_i
$$ Assuming for the moment that $n = 2$ and using induction later we have that
$$
\forall N \in \mathbb N \; \exists j \geq N \; y_j \in Y_1 \backslash Y_2
$$ With this we can make a subsequence $\bigl(y_{n_j}\bigr)_{j=0}^\infty$ in $Y_1 \backslash Y_2$. This sequence lies in $Y_1$ and thus has a convergent subsequence. This convergent subsequence of the subsequence will then also be a convergence subsequence of the original sequence. Now we may use induction on $n$.

Comment: @CameronBuie Of course; I should have realized that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your definition of compactness is that every sequence has a convergent subsequence. There is something you need to be cautious about, here: you are using $n$ for two different things! You use it first as the highest index of your $Y_i$s, and then as the index variable of your arbitrary sequence. Instead, let's go with $Y_1,...,Y_k$ as your compact sets.

Now, your proof gets the job done, but your detour into the "all but finitely many $y_n$ lie in some $Y_i$" possibility (how you start your proof) is unnecessary, as is induction. We can get there more simply if we recall that a union of finitely-many finite sets is again a finite set.

For $1\le i\le k,$ let $$\mathcal I_i=\{n\in\Bbb N:y_n\in Y_i\}.$$ (That is, $\mathcal I_i$ is the set of indices of sequence elements lying in $Y_i$.) Since the $y_n$ are all in $Y=\bigcup_{i=1}^kY_i,$ then $\bigcup_{i=1}^k\mathcal I_i=\Bbb N,$ whence at least one of the $\mathcal I_i$ is infinite (by the fact we recalled earlier). Without loss of generality, suppose $\mathcal I_1$ is infinite, so that the points $y_n$ lying in $Y_1$ form a subsequence of $\{y_n\}_{n=0}^\infty.$ Then we can proceed as you did.

Comment: This argument is no different from the OP's.  You're still using the Pigeonhole principal.  You've just phrased it differently.

Comment: @DWiggles: I'm glad you agree with me! My intention was to help the OP fix his/her argument. Now, if you feel that my correction is insufficient, please feel free to let me know, so that I can address it. Of course, if there is nothing wrong with my correction, please feel free to upvote.

Comment: @DWiggles: For what it's worth, your phrasing suggests to me that you think that you disagree with me. If that is the case, *please* point out what you believe to be wrong with my argument.

Comment: Your argument seems totally fine to me.

Answer (score 36):

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open cover of $Y$.  Since $\mathcal{O}$ is an open cover of each $Y_i$, there exists a finite subcover $\mathcal{O}_i \subset \mathcal{O}$ that covers each $Y_i$.  Then $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \mathcal{O}_i \subset \mathcal{O}$ is a finite subcover.  That's it; no need to deal with sequences.

Comment: I think that brevity is one of your qualities.

Comment: @J.G: While this is shorter and a simpler approach, it doesn't help the OP if they have not yet encountered the finite subcover definition of compactness (as seems to have been the case).

Comment: Wow, this method is Brilliant.

Comment: I was wondering why this answer is not set as the best answer . :-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'sCat: I suspect that this was not the accepted answer (despite being excellent, brief, and correct) because it didn't address the OP's question at the OP's level. I note that it still doesn't, but frankly, Ink has no real incentive to adjust. More upvotes might be garnered, and the downvote might be reversed, but this is already a highly successful answer, and the OP has already chosen my answer as the (most) helpful answer for his/her purposes.